# Reaction rate in terms of temperature change

Tags: concentration, temperature

For exothermic reaction where concentration changed in hard to measure, can I interpret the rate of reaction in terms of temperature change?
For example, if the experiment is iron rusting reaction with salt as a catalyst in water and I measure the temperature change and plot a graph of temperature vs time, can I say that the steeper trendline has a faster reaction rate?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE. In principle I guess that it could work but only under very well defined conditions,  same conc'n of reactants same volume liquid etc. But you will have the problem of different reactions generating different amounts of heat. You could perhaps try to normalise to a fixed final temperature change. Looks messy, but you may have no choice if you can't measure anything else.

Comment: @7_G.S.N So, basically, you're suggesting to measure $dT$, and then plot $\frac{dT}{dt}$, according to $\frac{Q}{t}=mS\frac{dT}{dt}$, and $\frac{dQ}{dt}=-\Delta H\frac{d(concentration)}{dt}$. One problem I see with this is that the reaction you're measuring the rate for should be a slow reaction, or $T$ will change very quickly. Generally, S is not constant with temperature, so you'll have to further consider $S(T)$. If the reaction is gas phase, then there will be pressure changes too. So, there are a lot of restrictions for choice of reaction by this method to determine the rate.

Comment: @ I initiate conduct the experiment with solid phase of iron and initiate it by contacting it with controlled amount of water. But I don't really get how your first equation is changed into the second one. Is 'H' in the second equation means theoretical enthalpy value? Also, what does 'S' mean in the first equation?

Comment: @7_G.S.N The first reaction will help us determine $\frac{Q}{t}$, and the second will, in turn, help us to determine the rate of change in concentration , which will be related to the heat output. They're two different equations - not deriving from each other. $S$ is specific heat capacity.